# Why my terminal keeps getting me this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i run my code i'm getting this error or just even if i run `clean` i get that error with `clean` instead of `ruby` at the beginning. I have installed the Ubuntu 18.04 subsystem on my Windows. And also i have installed the WSL remote. I'm getting this problem in **VS CODE**. I just started learning software enginering so i'm sorry if i'm giving not so clear info about my problem. Hope someone will help.

```
ruby : The term 'ruby' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify th 
    at the path is correct and try again.
    At line:1 char:1
    + ruby 01.corprime.rb
    + ~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ruby:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

in VS CODE.

Comment: where is your code situated, is it stored in the wsl, or is it stored in the windows bit? are you running "WSL1" or "WSL2" (huge difference)?

Answer (score 0):

clean and ruby by default is tools in. os
if msg said not recognized
so VS doesn't have path to run this commands or tools
try clear instead of clean
for ruby
try to install it and add it to path
or specify path of it when using in VS code

Comment: Thank you, the "Clear" command worked. But i didn't fully understand what you suggested me to do with ruby. Please, can you give me more info?

Comment: first check if ruby installed in your OS if not install it and try again if same problem after installing then search Google  for " add ruby to path OS xxxx"

Comment: I have installed Ruby 2.3.5 on my Ubuntu subsystem cuz i'm runing my code on Ubuntu, isn't enough?

Comment: sudo apt-get install ruby-full